# Elastic search vs lucene

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I know the difference between Elastic Search and Lucene as mentioned here.

[What is the difference between Lucene and Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793721/what-is-the-difference-between-lucene-and-elasticsearch)

Apart from scalability, fault tolerance and distributed nature of Elastic Search what is the core difference between the two.

- Does Elastic search provide any search feature which is better then lucene?

Answer (score 3):

Elasticsearch is Lucene++. ES leverages all the search, indexing and analysis features from Lucene + adds many additional ones, some of which are compositions of different Lucene features and some of which are completely unknown to Lucene and solely available at the ES level.

On top of that, ES adds a ton of features to make Lucene truly distributed, manageable, secured, etc.

Comment: Can u mention some features,which are available only in ES, as requested by OP.

Comment: http interface to query cluster, is ES feature ,its not given by lucene.

Comment: @val, can you provide exact definition of lucene++?And more about composition of different lucene features?

Comment: There is no exact definition of Lucene++, that's my way of saying that ES leverages Lucene and add tons of features on top of it. Lucene is just one library that ES uses. There is no "core difference" between ES and Lucene, it's like comparing a car (ES) with a car engine (Lucene). The best approach to this is to [start reading](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html) [some documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html) and [blog articles](https://www.elastic.co/blog).